# jQuery showing DIV when other DIV hover, doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, hidden

I'm fighting with some stupid issue, but I need help to solve it.

I have following html:

```
<div class="sekcja" id="michalm">
    <div id="michalm_opis" class="opis hidden"><b>Lorem ipsum</b><br/></div>
</div>
```

And at the end of page following code:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#michalm").hover(function () {
        $("#michalm_opis").removeClass("hidden");
    }, function () {
        $("#michalm_opis").addClass("hidden");
    });
});
</script>
```

It still causes (in Firebug):

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$(function(){
```

and, obviously, doesn't work.

I was trying to find solution, but still without success and time is going forward.

Comment: Then you need to be sure you've included the jQuery library with, for example, the following: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (replace the `1.9.1` with whatever version you'd prefer to include).

Comment: -1 did you just try a Google search on your error message?

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure jQuery is included (check that first), you may have included jQuery in compatibility mode (common for WordPress themes for example). You can solve that by either using `jQuery()` in place of `$()` - or you can wrap your entire script in a closure, which sets the variable.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //...your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Include this in your header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```